If $f \in H^{1}$ is it true that $f^{-1} \in H^{1}$ and $\nabla f^{-1} = -\nabla f/f^{2}$?
The title says it all. Suppose $f \in H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is real-valued and positive almost everywhere. How do I prove that $f^{-1} = 1/f \in H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and $\nabla f^{-1} = -\nabla f/f^{2}$?  I honestly don't even understand why $f^{-1} \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. It does not seem to follow from Hölder inequality. I also tried the reverse Hölder inequality, but got nowhere.

I wonder if there even is a function $f$ such that both $f$ and $\frac1f$ are in $L^2(\Bbb R^n)$...

@SassatelliGiulio wouldn't that mean that $1\in L^1(\Bbb R^n)$?

@SineoftheTime That $1\in L^1(\Bbb R^n)$, but point taken, thank you.

Corretto :) @SassatelliGiulio

It is simply not true: We surely have
$$
\exp(-|x|^2) \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n),
$$
but
$$
\exp(|x|^2) \notin H^1(\mathbb{R}^n).
$$

Thanks! I think this can only be true if we use mollifiers: $\varphi/f \in H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ for $\varphi$ smooth and compactly supported.
